# PHP REST API Авторизация для Android

Tags: php, auth, аутентификация

Какие есть подходы для реализации авторизации на стороне PHP из Android приложения. Я не совсем понимаю серверную часть. Задача примерно следующая.

1) Пользователь вводит логин и пароль в Android приложении, уходит POST запрос на myApi.com/auth.php (тут проблем нет).

2) При верных данных как сохранить на сервере информацию о том, что User01 выполнил вход и что ему вернуть, что бы после перехода на следующий экран при запросе myApi.com/news.php сервер понял, что обращается к нему именно User01.

Вопрос как сделать это правильно? Какие есть подходы и стандарты. Подскажите направления и литературу.

Я верно понял, что могу сам генерировать "токен" и хранить его в БД. Но это каждый раз при обращении скажем к myApi.php передавать токен и искать в БД информацию об авторизации? Т.е. этот вариант не является оптимальным.

В общем, в процессе ответов я буду переформулировать и дополнять вопрос, т.к. на данный момент имею слабое представление об этом.

P.S. Я смотрю в сторону PHP фреймворков тоже, но мне нужен только REST функционал. От непонимания процесса авторизации не могу сделать выбор.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Т.е. этот вариант не является оптимальным." - если смотреть с точки зрения пхп, то да, этот вариант не оптимален, но и не слишком затратен.

Происходит все примерно следующим образом:

1. Введенные данные с приложения уходят к примеру на "myApi.com/auth.php"
2. Сервер, проверяя введенные данные (к примеру логин и пароль) "генерирует токен"/"берет из базы уже сгенерированный токен" и отправляет его клиенту.
3. Клиент теперь должен передавая любые запросы в след сбрасывать свой токен (если эти данные к примеру относятся к данному пользователю и больше ни к кому другому, на примере страницы с балансом пользователя)
4. Сервер принимая запрос на получение данных о балансе не может идентифицировать пользователя, если нет токена, НО! Токен то вы присылаете, а значит данный токен и есть идентификация пользователя. Т.е. По токену можно найти кому он принадлежит (user_id) и уже затем выгребсти данные по балансу данного пользователя.

Не забывайте, что есть куча разных технологий хранения данных, и к примеру, "токен" => "user_id" можно хранить не в базе (постгрес, мускл, оракл), а к примеру в memcache (memcached), reddis или любом другом месте.

Comment: А есть какие либо стандарты или наработанные и проверенные решения?

Comment: есть уйма решений, как проверенных, так и работающих по сей день. Что конкретно Вам нужно?

Comment: Можно использовать API токен или сессии. API выдается один раз для пользователя, сессии используются как обычно - после логина выдается печенька, которую пересылают в заголовке запроса для аутентификации.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov это все понятно, но человек упорно думает, что получив токен, нужно как-то сопоставить его с пользователем, а это лишний запрос в базу и как-бы "не оптимально".

Comment: @Евгений -  посмотрите на исходники того же опенкарта (если мы про пхп говорим), как там организована авторизация и работа с пользователем. Более того, так почти все на пхп работает

Comment: @kevin, ну что же, пусть выстроит это у себя в голове, может поймет, что иначе вроде как и логической цепочки не создашь. Сессионные данные где-то хранятся и загружаются, это может не обязательно быть БД (https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/session)

Comment: @kevin, я понимаю что это нужно где то хранить. И бд вполне подходит. Но опять же. Хочу разобраться в этом вопросе более подробно. Сейчас читаю memcached. И посмотреть исходники тоже хорошая идея. Ещё не совсем понимаю механизм сессий($_SESSION) в php. Правильно ли хранить токен сессии и передавать в  качестве куков. Сейчас подтягиваю знания по этим вопросам.